# Delphi 11.3 compiler directives for "Development" and "Application store" modes

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio, compiler-directives

Please tell me the Delphi 11.3 compiler directives for development modes and the application store,
if they exist.

A switch is needed for different logic.

Development is carried out in the FireMonkey environment for iOS.

[image]